How to validate self-build GNU toolchain and newlib?
I am working on an embedded system, where there is ARM SOC and RTOS.
I have built GNU toolchain with newlib for this embedded system, and did very basic testing.
Now before I can be sure to use the self-build toolchain, I want to test it (and newlib) thoroughly, but I did find out how to do that.
So is there any test suite to validate that the GCC and newlib are built correctly, and would generate correct codes for the ARM SOC, so that they can be used in product??

binutils, GCC and newlib each have comprehensive test suites. You’ll need to install Dejagnu (the dejagnu package in most distributions). Then, from each build directory, run

make check for binutils and GCC
make check-target-newlib for newlib

The test suites handle cross-compilation correctly; they won’t attempt to run non-native code. You can configure Dejagnu to test binaries on the target but I haven’t done that in a while, so I don’t remember how to do it off-hand.
